# Cannot bind to the property on the target control exception c#

Tags: c#, data-binding

this is my code 
I run `winform` application And I want to bind the index of `Listbox` to an index running in seprate `class` and `Thread`

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var binding = new Binding("ScriptListBox", ScriptHandler.DomainScriptHanlderAgent, "ScriptCounter", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    ScriptListBox.DataBindings.Add(binding);

}

public static class ScriptHandler
{
    public static DomainLayer.DomainScriptHandler DomainScriptHanlderAgent = new DomainLayer.DomainScriptHandler();
}
```

here I implement the the property changed

```
public class DomainScriptHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly object ScriptLocker = new object();
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int scriptCounter;
    private ISynchronizeInvoke invoker;
    public Stack<string> ScriptCurrentTree = new Stack<string>();
    /// <summary>
    /// each move this will fire to form to move index step further
    /// </summary>
    public int ScriptCounter
    {
        get { return scriptCounter; }
        set
        {
            scriptCounter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            Action action = () => handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            invoker.Invoke(action, null);
        }
    }
```

but when I run it I get " `Cannot bind to the property 'ScriptListBox' on the target control.`" exception in `class Form` at `ScriptListBox.DataBindings.Add(binding)`

what am I missing here please ?

Comment: I believe you need `new Binding("SelectedIndex",` rather than `new Binding("ScriptListBox",`